# Read more button for item

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a `telerik:RadRotator` with `ItemTemplate`, i have `<a href="#" class="read_more"><br/>...voir plus</a>` of evry item with `JQuery`.

```
$(function () {
    $('.news-info').each(function (event) {
        var max_length = 300;
        debugger;
        if ($(this).html().length > max_length) {
            var short_content = $(this).html().substr(0, max_length);
            var long_content = $(this).html().substr(max_length);

            $(this).html(short_content +
                '<a href="#" class="read_more"><br/>...voir plus</a>' +
                '<span class="more_text" style="display:none;">' + long_content + '</span>');

            $(this).find('a.read_more').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).parents('.news-item').find('.more_text').show();
                $(".news-item").toggleClass('expanded');
                $(".news-info").toggleClass('expanded');
            });
        }
    });
});

  <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="news-item">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50px; height: auto;">
                        <img src="~/Img/ImgLettreNEWS/NEW.png" runat="server" alt="Avatar" class="news-avatar" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblNewsTitle" CssClass="news-title" Text="BOUZID Ghassen" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">

                        <div runat="server" id="DivHmtlContent" class="news-info">
                        ...........
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <asp:Image ID="Img_News" runat="server" class="RotatorImage" Style="width: 82px; height: 59px" />
        <br />
        <%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TITRE")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

My problem that when i click the read more button, all items are extended

Comment: Please improve formatting on your question, it's very hard to read anything like this. Also remove any unnecessary code.

Comment: Can you provide the generated HTML so it is easier to answer your question.

Comment: I want to create a read more button for each item in my list.

Comment: I understand. The problem probably lies in the way you are using the jQuery selector. It would be easier if you would show us the generated HTML so we can spot the problem.

Comment: @WouterBouwman, yes it is my problem,

Comment: @WouterBouwman Good on your for pointing it out!